# Hide navigation in _Layout.cshtml file when displaying the login screen

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, master-pages

I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC so this problem has me stumped.

When a client goes to my website they are presented with a login screen. I am using a layout/master page to keep the look consistent across the website. The problem is I don't want to display the navigation menu on the login page only subsequent pages after the client has logged in.

I am using forms authentication so i do not want to set a persistent cookie due to the nature of the data/content for security reasons so i can't use:

```
@if(Request.isAuthenticated)
{
   //display menu
}

else
{
   //don't display menu
}
```

The other problem with this solution that I had thought of is that if i'm hiding the nav bar then the content will not fill the entire height of the screen as i am using percentages. By this I mean that when the nav bar is hidden all content will move up and there will be a strip of empty space at the bottom.

What is the best way to do this?.

UPDATE:

Based on solutions already provided I have got this working via the following:

*_Layout.cshtml file*

I set the Session["isAuthenticated"] variable upon login.

```
 @if(Session["isAuthenticated"] != null)
            {
                <div id="navigation">
                    <a href="#" id="menu_toggle"> Show/Close Menu </a>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li><a href="#"> Accounts </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Calculate/Sumbit Quote </a> </li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Messages </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Contact Us </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Settings </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>

                <div id="normalContentContainer" class="content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            }

            else
            {
                <div id="loginContentContainer" class="content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            }
```

*style sheet*

```
.content
 {
  width: 100%;
  //min-height: 79%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px 30px 20px 30px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CECCCC; 
  border-left: 1px solid #CECCCC; 
  border-right: 1px solid #CECCCC;
  //border-bottom: 3px solid #BABABA;
  margin-top: 0.4%;
}

#normalContentContainer
{
  height: 73.3%;
}

#loginContentContainer
{
   height: 79.3%;
}
```

This works perfectly but is it considered good practice to do this sort of thing.

Comment: I, personally, would do it as per my example. If I need separate styling for the login page only, I would put that styling directly onto the login page view rather than the master layout. You could for example add a div to the login page that accounts for the 6% difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Part: What I do is, once the user is authenticated then store a User object (for example) in the session. On the layout page check for the presence of the user instance on the session state and display accordingly. This works quite well too, when the session expires.

Second Part: Put your nav in a separate 'outer' container and set the height etc on the outer container so it fits the app. Then only hide the 'inner' nav.

```
<div id="outercontainer">
  @if(Session["AuthenticatedUser"]!=null)
  {
  <div id="navigation">
    // nav etc
  </div>
  }
</div>

<div id="maincontent">
   @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Here are some pretty crude examples, but it should give you the idea (the last div is always rendered in the same place).

Example when not logged in: http://jsfiddle.net/p8y0ffnc/2

Example when logged in: http://jsfiddle.net/uef0bk54/

Comment: but wouldn't this affect the positioning of element contained within @RenderBody() ?

Comment: without knowing the exact layout of your page I cannot really say. In my apps I usually either a) only show a login page if not logged in (no nav at all) or b) replace the nav options with a 'sign in' option,

Comment: yes this is what i'm trying to achieve except for that I do not require a sign in option as the user only has access to the login page unless logged in meaning they will already be sitting on the login page.

Comment: See edits: These are examples are pretty crude but they demonstrate the structure of the resulting elements.

Comment: thank you all for the help. I have something working. I have updated the question please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: OK I see the problem you had now! My answer assumed (incorrectly) that you had RenderBody once - see edit.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of hiding the navigation bar for a specific page would be to check the page title.

```
@if (@ViewData["Title"] != "Login")
{
// Show NavBar
}
else{
// Show an Empty box to fill the space
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking todo. I have a nav link that I only want displayed if its set in the DB